# Animate tableView Cell on didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I would like to resize my `tableView` cell when the user selects a row, the cell becomes smaller then larger again.  This is what I have tried so far:

```
#pragma mark UITableView Delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

// My animation

    cell.contentView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.95,0.95);
    cell.contentView.alpha = 1.f;

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"button" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2];
    cell.contentView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1,1);
    cell.contentView.alpha = 1.0f;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

This is my tableView data source:

```
#pragma mark UITableView Datasource

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

// Set up cell

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:21];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    }


// Images in my cell

    NSArray *images = @[@"Songs", @"Albums", @"Artists", @"Playlists"];

    UIImageView *cellImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:images[indexPath.row]]];

    cellImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 90, 90);
    [cell addSubview:cellImage];

    return cell;
}
```

But this does not work.  The image in the cell simply stays the same size.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I seriously advise going with a `UICollectionView` for something like this. With it, you only have to call `performBatchUpdates` and you can put any frame setting inside of it's block. It's practically magic!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can or should do what you ask about, but if you can it would probably be with a custom UITableViewCell. But, you might be able to fake it with a custom cell, maybe with a UIView that holds all the cell's contents. The UIView would animate inside the cell, and if you are not showing separators on the table it could look like the cell itself is animating. So basically you're hiding the actual cell, and using a UIView in the cell to simulate animating the cell. Maybe like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
    self.customCell.frame = CGRectMake(110, 20, 100, 20);
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:SLIDE_TIME delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
        self.customCell.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 60);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {


    }];
}];
```